# Is any Newton equation an Euler-Lagrange equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $$ r'' = \mathrm{F}(r', r)$$

be Newton equation in one variable whith $\mathrm{F}$ locally Lipschitz.

Is there a function $\mathcal{L}(r',r)$ such that the Newton equation is in fact Euler-Lagrange equation $$ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial r} = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial r'} \quad ?$$

I know that it is true for a conservative force field, but what about the general case?

Comment: Related MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/q/146042/13917

Answer (score 1):

your first question is also known as the inverse problem for the Lagrangian mechanics.

Answering your question, there exists a necessary and sufficient condition in order that a second order ode $F(r'',r',r)=0$ be of Euler-Lagrange kind.
This condition, called after Helmholtz, is expressed by the system
$$\left\{\begin{gathered} 
\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial r_j''}=\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial r_i''},\\
\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial r_j'}+\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial r_i'}=2\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial r_i''},\\
\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial r_j}-\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial r_i}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial r_j'}-\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial r_i'}\right),
\end{gathered}\right.$$
where the Einstein summation convention is active.